# Key establishment protocols in WSN

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, encryption-symmetric

I'm trying to compare the key establishment protocol i'm working on with others already proposed but i am not able to find any research papers in which symmetric pairwise keys are established using public key cryptography. Can anyone suggest a list of research papers available on the web for free?

Comment: Maybe [D–H](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie–Hellman_key_exchange) is relevant?

Comment: I actually meant to see if anyone has implemented it and see the results obtained, either using ECC or D-H. Any research papers on that please?